# What means the grey circle around a called existing action?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have calls to existing actions. Some action-icons in the Test-Flow-View are pictured with a grey circle on its icon. 
Where did that grey circle come from?

Thanks!

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Grey circle indicate that action is nested in a conditional statement.

Icons in test flow pane are described in QTP User Guide. Follow this path: "HP QuickTest Professional User Guide > Working with the QuickTest Panes > Test Flow Pane > Test Flow Pane User Interface > Item Type Icons "